# YouTube API Compliance Audit

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Today I received email from **noreply@youtube.com** with next text:

Dear YouTube API Developer,

We are currently conducting a mandatory compliance review of your YouTube Data API Project. The review is to assess your compliance to our YouTube API Services Developer Policies (link) and to learn about how our service is being used.
At your convenience in the next seven (7) business days, please complete and submit the following information:

1. A fully functional demo account, including a username and password with which we may access your API Client. The demo account you provide will be used only for compliance inspection and the credentials will not be shared.
2. A fully completed Youtube API Audit Form
3. Screenshots of how your API Client and its users access and use the YouTube API Services
4. Documents relating to your implementation, access and use of YouTube API Services

For reference, your project number is 0000000000
Please ensure that all required supporting materials are submitted and sufficient, and all questions are answered thoroughly. If this is not the correct or preferred API contact email, or if you would like us to cc any other contacts on future emails, please let us know.

Thanks,
YouTube API Services team
YouTube, LLC 901 Cherry Ave, San Bruno, CA 94066

**Can someone explain to me - where should I send the answer?**

Comment: Have you hit the reply button? Maybe the email contains a separate reply-to address.

Comment: @analog-nico yeah, I already tried it. But, I got "Message not delivered" from mailer-daemon@googlemail.com

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 4):

This seems like an excessive requirement for a largely free API, but at any rate there is a link in the email to the submission form:

https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form

Comment: Yep, I submitted this form. If it works - I will text here

Comment: Have you received any response yet @IvanKucher?

Comment: @Kaffekoppen nope

Comment: @IvanKucher Hey, Any update on this? Did you ever receive anything back from them this after you filled this out? I got one of these emails today....

Comment: @code I never filled it out because my app that used the youtube api is defunct